# Angular / Link is not functional in template / directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have this code in angular accounts_directives:

```
(function() {
  app.directive('accounts', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: '/templates/funds/accounts.html',
      scope: {
        localValue: '=accounts'
      },
      controller: function($scope, $state) {
        var ctrl;
        ctrl = this;
        this.state = $state;
        if (window.location.hash === "") {
          this.state.transitionTo("deposits.currency", {
            currency: Account.first().currency
          });
        }
        $scope.accounts = Account.all();
        console.log(Account.all());
        this.selectedCurrency = window.location.hash.split('/')[2] || Account.first().currency;
        this.currentAction = window.location.hash.split('/')[1] || 'deposits';
        $scope.currency = this.selectedCurrency;
        this.isSelected = function(currency) {
          return this.selectedCurrency === currency;
        };
        this.isDeposit = function() {
          return this.currentAction === 'deposits';
        };
        this.isWithdraw = function() {
          return this.currentAction === 'withdraws';
        };
        this.deposit = function(account) {
          ctrl.state.transitionTo("deposits.currency", {
            currency: account.currency
          });
          ctrl.selectedCurrency = account.currency;
          return ctrl.currentAction = "deposits";
        };
        this.withdraw = function(account) {
          ctrl.state.transitionTo("withdraws.currency", {
            currency: account.currency
          });
          ctrl.selectedCurrency = account.currency;
          return ctrl.currentAction = "withdraws";
        };
        return (this.event = function() {
          return Account.bind("create update destroy", function() {
            return $scope.$apply();
          });
        })();
      },
      controllerAs: 'accountsCtrl'
    };
  });

}).call(this);
```

Link in template seems like that:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="accountsCtrl.deposit(account); $event.preventDefault()" class="ng-binding">Deposit</a>
```

But when clicking, nothing happen.
When I put accountsCtrl.deposit(account); to console the result is Uncaught ReferenceError: accountsCtrl is not defined at :1:1

Need understand, why the accountsCtrl isn't defined even the presence of code in application.
Can somebody help me how t find the solution?
Maybe some debugging, but try finding the solution long long time and no idea how to fix it.

Comment: under your controllerAs: 'accountsCtrl', add bindToController:true

Comment: Thank you, but no effect after changing

Comment: BTW: Url seems like that 'http://localhost:3000/funds?#!/deposits/cny'

Comment: ok let's start from the basic question: are you sure you added this file inside your files list? is at least your directive correctly rendered on the page?

Comment: Sure, I can get the file from developer tools. Also inserted inside. I am thinking there will be bigger problem in case other functionality is fine

Comment: One thing I found is that, when I add the Url to browser and push enter, page load. But not by clicking on the link.